Failure to display MsgBox
I have written the below VBA code which will give me a warning message when I open the file if the desired condition is met. But when I save the file and open it again, it doesn't show me anything.
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("4")
    
    If ws.Range("D2").Value <= ws.Range("F2").Value Then
        MsgBox "go to 4"
    End If
End Sub

The numbers in the desired cells are entered correctly. I have ticked the macro activation in the settings. I have also received help from ChatGPT but it did not work.
I want it to show the MsgBox when I open the file if the condition is met.

Is the code placed in the Workbook module?

Side note: Do you have a sheet named "4"? Or do you want to acces sheet number 4?

@FunThomas
sheet name is 4

But when I save the file and open it again, it doesn't show me anything Do you save it as XLSM? any security settings blocking macros? Did you check if the code is there in the newly saved file?
